# Finite automata NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How can I construct finite automata accepting the following language?

NFA : The set of strings over $\{a, b\}$ in which every $a$ is followed by $b$ or $ab$.

[My try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGjyP.png)

Comment: What goes wrong if you try to draw one?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I tried but I miss some cases and  I don't know how to do.

Comment: Show your attempt, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt your automata accepts $a\notin \mathcal L$ so it is not correct.

---

The words that the automata should accept are $b,bb,bb,ab,aab,bbbabbbaabbb,\dots$

I think that this should work:
[image]

Comment: But isn't it DFA?We need NFA.

Comment: @bambam Every DFA is also an NFA

Comment: Yes, it is true.Thanks

Comment: @bambam  you are welcome